# Using kettle as Saiku data source

Tags: pentaho, kettle, mondrian, saiku

I want use saiku in Pentaho user console. But i want to create in the ETL (PDI or kettle) all the dimensions and measures and show them in Saiku. I am able to use a kettle step as a DS of a chart from the CDE c-tools. Is posible to use the same approach with Saiku, or is there a way to fill a mondrian scheme with the PDI?

Thanks

Comment: An optiq adapter for PDI, that'd be interesting! PDI EE does have the thin jdbc driver, which does this.

Comment: you are right, in the EE there is a driver but not for the CE.